# replace class of a span by id inside a 'a' by id inside a div by id

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to replace the class of a "span" element inside an "a" element inside a "div" element.

I have this div:

```
<div id="songList" ng-repeat="el in tracksList">
<a ng-click="playSelectedSong($index)" class="list-group-item" id="{{$index}}"><h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><span id="playStopSpan" class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>{{el.title}}</h4><p class="list-group-item-text"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></span>Stats: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span> {{el.playback_count}} </p></a>
```

And I want to replace the class in the span element with the id **playStopSpan**.

My document tree is as I understand:
**Div**-->**a**-->**span** for each element in tracksList.

I have tried several approaches, but have not nailed it yet. So far I have this:

```
$("#songList > #"+songNr+" > span#playStopSpan").removeClass().addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-pause");
```

**songNr** is the value of **($index)** in the ng-click.

Comment: Use ng-class https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass instead of mixing in jquery dom manipulation in your controller.

Comment: Of course! Silly me, forgot all about ng-class.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it using ng-class:

```
<span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{ 'glyphicon-pause': el.paused, 'glyphicon-play': !el.paused}">

  $scope.tracksList = [
      {paused: true, title: 'First song', playback_count: 0}
    ];

  $scope.togglePause = function (track) {
    track.paused = !track.paused;
  }
```

In the demo Playing is crossed though if it's not playing.

http://plnkr.co/edit/UNcnBUP7eGewI7YRAOHU?p=preview

Comment: Well, almost like that, but I did not propose the condition in my question so It would be impossible for you to know that. I needed to check the condition if the el $index was equal or not to the selectedIndex. So I just put $scope.selectedIndex in my directive controller and added the condition [$index==selectedIndex] to my ng-class. Thanks anyway, you put me on the right track.